# Ejecución secuencial de funciones asíncronas

Tags: javascript, async-await

Tengo una función la cual tiene dos sentencias que se ejecutan de manera asincrona.

```
const returnedPackage = await getAssetRegistry('es.test.Asset')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.add(package);
    });

await setEnclosingAsset(recoveredVals, assetInfoObj['assetId']);

return returnedPackage;
```

La primera lambda realiza el guardado pero sin llegar a terminar, se me ejecuta la segunda sentencia. En la segunda sentencia, con el identificador. Realizo una búsqueda del valor que se está guardando en la sentencia de arriba. Y digo guardando por que me devuelve una excepción diciendo que no se ha encontrado valor con ese identificador. Entonces imagino que ambas se ejecutan de manera paralela.

Pense que igual estaba haciendo mal el guardado pero si comento la línea del await setEnclosingAsset()...... El guardado si me lo hace de manera correcta.

¿Alguna sugerencia para solventar este error de flujo de ejecuciones?

**EDIT**

Probe lo siguiente pero persiste el error

```
await getAssetRegistry('es.test.Asset')
    .then(function (assetRegistry) {
        newPackage = assetRegistry.add(package);
    })
    .then(function () {
        setEnclosingAsset(recoveredVals, assetInfoObj['assetId']);
    });
```

Comment: Yo hace poco hice algo parecido, con el mismo problema. Solucion? un array que iba guardando los elementos guardados, y al hacer la segunda llamada, lo consulto.

Comment: Si yo planteé la estrategia de en vez de almacenarlo en un array almacenarlo en una variable. Pero no estoy lograndolo.

Comment: Es difícil entenderlo, por que yo te puedo explicar lo que hice, pero no tendrá nada que ver con lo que tu estas haciendo. Yo intentaba hacerlo 100% paralelo, y no lo conseguí, al final opte por pequeños bloque y muy rápidos

Comment: Mi intención es justo la contraria. Hacerlo de manera secuencial. Pero imagino que haya algún tipo de función que gestione esto. Estoy a la caza de esa sentencia XD

Comment: Has provado de añadir un callback para los casos de error? es posible que este fallando la ejecución de el primer then

Comment: `assetRegistry.add(package);` es una promesa?

Comment: Estoy dando vueltas a tu código y debo estar espeso hoy porque no entiendo el problema que tienes :( ¿Puedes explicar con más detalles qué quieres conseguir?

Comment: La ejecución de assetRegistry.add(package); retorna una promesa si

Comment: El problema que tengo es que necesito hacer un proceso que cuenta con dos pasos. Pero el segundo depende de que termine el primer paso. El primer paso añade un registro y en la linea de abajo trato de recuperarlo. Pero al no haber terminado de hacer la primera tarea la segunda falla y me aparece un error en consola que me dice que no existe el valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código que dejas de ejemplo, el problema que planteas en mi opinión tiene que ver con que tienes al menos 2 promesas anidadas. Para ejecutar algo cuando termina una promesa puedes utilizar el `await` **o bien** el callback del `.then()` pero hay que hacerlo con cada promesa, sino va a quedar una parte asíncrona. Te dejo un ejemplo funcional con promesas anidadas, en este ejemplo un solo `await` es suficiente porque ambas promesas ejecutan el `resolve()` pero podría no ser así. Podrías ver cuando algo es una promesa o no haciendo `console.log`'s

```js
let promesasAnidadas = new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    const resultado1rapromesa = "primera promesa ";
    resolve(new Promise((resolve2) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve2(resultado1rapromesa + " segunda promesa")
      }, 1000);
    }));
  }, 1000);
});

(async () => {
  const resultado1 = await promesasAnidadas;
  //SE VA A EJECUTAR PRIMERO
  console.log(resultado1);

  //SE VA A EJECUTAR TERCERO
  const resultado2 = promesasAnidadas.then(r => console.log(r));

  //SE VA A EJECUTAR SEGUNDO
  console.log("se ejecuta despues del resultado1 pero antes del resultado2");

})();
```

En el código del segundo intento que haces, el segundo `then()` lo va a ejecutar si lo anterior es una promesa, entonces quizá deberías hacer algo como:

```
await getAssetRegistry('es.test.Asset')
    .then(function (assetRegistry) {
        return assetRegistry.add(package);// solo si se retorna una promesa aqui
    })
    .then(function (resultado) {
        //hacer algo con resultado
        setEnclosingAsset(recoveredVals, assetInfoObj['assetId']);
    });
```

Comment: He tratado de hacer la implementacion que me comentastes, concretamente la ultima sugerencia. Pero no doy con la solucion si hago console log de resultado me aparece undefined. Y sigue sin encontrar el valor guardado de la funcion de arriba

Answer (score 0):

El motivo por el que esto no te funciona es que JavaScript ejecuta las secuencias asíncronas de manera "inteligente", es decir, que solo espera cuando tiene que esperar.

Cuando tienes un código como este

```
    async result = getData()
    async doWork()
```

Javascript no espera, porque asume que getData y doWork no están relacionadas y las lanza en paralelo. Esto es porque en realidad las funciones async no son más que promesas que se lanzan y autoresuelven.

Para forzar la espera, debes hacer que haya código que use la primera función antes de que la segunda se ejecute. Por ejemplo:

```
    async result = getData()
    async doWork(result)
```

Como para poder hacer doWork necesitas el valor de result, Javascript esperará a ejecutar  la segunda función.

En tu código no usas el valor de returnedPackage en tu código, con lo que ambas se ejecutan en paralelo.
Si haces algo como

```
    if(returnedPackage) {
        await setEnclosingAsset(recoveredVals, assetInfoObj['assetId']);
    }
```

La segunda función no se lanzará hasta que se ejecute la primera.